# What’s the word for doing/learning something in the moment although we aren’t good at it?

Tags: single-word-requests

We just have to do it because the situation demands so

Comment: I think this is a nice question, but I'd suggest you give an example of such a situation and/or put in a sample sentence leaving a blank for your word.

Comment: A- not sure how to do it ...B- me neither, just ____....know this word just forgot it..can’t remember not matter how hard I try to think

Comment: What's the situation? I could edit your question if you gave me some background. I think otherwise people will vote to close it.

Comment: What do you mean by “in the moment”?  That is not English.

Comment: PS To edit you just click 'edit' under the question. I think everyone can edit their own questions no matter how new they are to the site.

Comment: Perhaps [**ad lib**](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/ad_lib) but S Conroy's answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest [improvise](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/improvise?s=t)

> verb (used with object), im·pro·vised, im·pro·vis·ing.
>  to compose
>   and perform or deliver without previous preparation; extemporize: *to
>   improvise an acceptance speech*.
>  to compose, play, recite, or
>   sing (verse, music, etc.) on the spur of the moment.
>  to make,
>   provide, or arrange from whatever materials are readily available: *We
>   improvised a dinner from yesterday's leftovers.*
>  verb (used
>   without object), im·pro·vised, im·pro·vis·ing. to compose, utter,
>   execute, or arrange anything extemporaneously: *When the actor forgot
>   his lines he had to improvise.*

In school if we hadn't studied for an exam we used the phrase (idiom)
[to wing it](https://www.betteratenglish.com/english-idioms-to-wing-it-to-improvise): *I'll just have to wing it and hope for the best.*

> Meaning
>
> To wing it is an idiom that means to improvise, to do something
>   without proper preparation or time to rehearse. People often talk
>   about winging it when they have to do something difficult that they
>   didn’t have time to prepare — like a make speech or give a
>   presentation. They might say something like "Sorry if I seem a bit
>   disorganized, I’m totally winging it." You tell people that you’re
>   winging it, that you’re improvising, so that they won’t expect too
>   much from you, or so that they will be more forgiving if you make a
>   mistake.

Comment: Yup!!..that’s the word